# Create Maven Project in Command Line VS in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I read in some tutorial , we can create Maven project in command line by

1. `mvn archetype:generate`
2. and then `mvn eclipse:eclipse`
3. and then Go to Eclipse and Import Existing Maven Project

Alternatively, I also see that we can create Maven project directly from Eclipse

1. In Eclipse : File - New - Maven Project ... Done

My questions

- Why we need to create Maven project from command line if we can create it directly in Eclipse ?
- Do we need to download Maven from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) to create and use Maven project?  I see Eclipse Neon 2 can create Maven project without downloading those jars.

Thank You.

Comment: 1 - Not everyone would have eclipse installed (for whatever reason), 2 - Eclipse has an embedded version of maven, so no (though I really recommend not to use it (lots of head neck with it) ).

Comment: Using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` is not recommended anymore cause it's deprecated. You should use the m2e within Eclipse and just import it into Eclipse. You should always have installed command line of Maven cause there are sometime issues related to the differences between Eclipse and command line. Always test your project to build fine on command line and than import it into Eclipse..